# OpenGL texture is all black when rendered with shader

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, textures, shader

I have a very simple OpenGL application that renders only one textured quad. This is my code, which works just fine (the textured quad appears just fine):

```
// Bind the test texture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTestTexture);


// Draw the quad
glBegin(GL_QUADS);

glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(x, y + (float)height, 0.0f);

glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(x + (float)width, y + (float)height, 0.0f);

glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(x + (float)width, y, 0.0f);

glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(x, y, 0.0f);

glEnd();
```

Then I wanted to intoduce a simple shader. So I modified my code a little:

```
// Use shader and point it to the right texture
auto texLocation = glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "tex");
glUseProgram(mProgram);
glUniform1i(texLocation, mTestTexture);

// Draw the quad
// Same drawing code as before...
```

Vertex shader:

```
void main(void)
{
 gl_Position     = ftransform();
 gl_TexCoord[0]  = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2D tex;

void main()
{
    vec4 color = texture2D(tex, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Now all I get is a **black quad** :-(

I already tried and tested a lot of things:

- The shaders compile fine (no errors)
- The quad is visible (vertex shader seems OK)
- If I change the shader to produce a fixed color ("gl_FragColor = vec4(1,0,0,1);") my quad becomes red -> fragment shader is doing something!
- glGetError() does not return any errors
- My texLocation, mProgram and mTestTexture all seem to be valid IDs

Does anyone have an idea why I won't see my texture when using the shader?

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
glUniform1i(texLocation, mTestTexture);
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^ texture object
```

Texture unit *indexes* are bound to samplers, not texture objects.

Use texture unit zero instead:

```
glUniform1i(texLocation, 0);
```